# VBA Excel: which one is better and faster: using one variant matrix for a range or several arrays for each column?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant

I need to use values from several columns based on a row value. Is it better and faster to create variant matrix array and store all columns in that array then search and deploy values from that array, or create an array for each column, considering that there can be several thousand rows and the values are used multiple times?

Example: We have the following data:

[image]

If the person joined before 01-Jan-13, I want to deduct due amount from equity. Is it better to declare a variant array like

```
Dim matrix() as Variant
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim cols(4) as String: cols(0) = "A': cols(1) = "B": cols(2) = "C": cols(3) = "D"
Dim i as Integer
Dim b as Integer: b = 2 'beginning row
Dim j as Integer: j = 4 'number of lines

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 0 to UBound(cols)
  matrix(i) = Range(cols(i) & b & ":" & cols(i) & (b + j)).value2
End if
```

or

Declare separate four arrays, like

```
Dim arr1() as String
Dim arr2() as Date
Dim arr3() as Integer
Dim arr4() as Integer
```

Of course I can directly use data from cells by directly referencing cells as well, but as I use this multi-thousand-row data  multiple times it makes more sense to store them in array.

Comment: I think the speed difference question is an academic one. In practice, you won't notice any difference. Variant needs more memory, but even that is irrelevant even for a few thousand lines. The 32 bit version of Excel has 4 GiB available. Therefore, from a pragmatic point of view, I would use the Variant array, because it is the simpler data structure both to create and to access from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy a Range to an Array and Vice Versa

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeductDue()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the data (no headers) range ('rg').
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from columns 2-4 ('Date' to 'Due') to an array ('sData').
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = rg.Columns(2).Resize(, 3).Value
    
    ' Wrtie the values from column 6 ('Equity') column to an array ('dData').
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = rg.Columns(6).Value
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the arrays and calculate...
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
        If Year(sData(r, 1)) < 2013 Then
            dData(r, 1) = dData(r, 1) - sData(r, 3)
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the result to a column range, e.g.:
    rg.Columns(6).Value = dData ' overwrite Equity with the deducted values
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are many columns, it may be noticeably faster to read all the data into a single matrix in one go. There is a large overhead with every transfer of data between Excel and VBA. A larger data transfer is not much slower than a small data transfer, but many data transfers is a lot slower than a single transfer.

Here is an excellent source of detail:

> Data transfer between worksheet cells and VBA variables is an expensive operation that should be kept to a minimum. You can considerably increase the performance of your Excel application by passing arrays of data to the worksheet, and vice versa, in a single operation rather than one cell at a time. If you need to do extensive calculations on data in VBA, you should transfer all the values from the worksheet to an array, do the calculations on the array, and then, possibly, write the array back to the worksheet. This keeps the number of times data is transferred between the worksheet and VBA to a minimum. It is far more efficient to transfer one array of 100 values to the worksheet than to transfer 100 items at a time.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx